# Underscore appears instead of space when typed in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, whitespace

When I type space in Notepad++, an underscore appears. Can you help me with this issue?

[image: This is the case]

Comment: Is there really an underscore in the file, or is it the way a space is being displayed (use `notepad` to check)?

Comment: @AFH It must be actually a space, or else the syntax highlighting would break.

Comment: it's a space.i am asking how to disable underscore

Comment: It may be that the font you're using has an underscore for a space.  What font are you using, and have you tried a different one?

Comment: theme is deep black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't why you having this problem, will you just try to reinstall the notepad++.
May be that will help.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have enabled the option to show white space and tab characters.

Click on the View menu and select "Show Symbol" and un-check "Show White Space and TAB".

Comment: i am not checked that.when i try to check it the underscore white color changes to pink and a small dot above it.

Comment: @ChrisHarris - I got the same pink dot (but no underscore) when I tried that setiing, so I assumed this wasn't the answer. You'll have to try the other suggestions and change font and theme. You may not like the result, but it will isolate the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me following worked, sharing in case if it helps others. Goto

> Settings -> Style Configurator

and select `Default Style` in `Style list`.
Then, deselect `Underline` from `Font Style` in the right side panel.

Answer (score -2):

Press Ins button in between the Pause Break & Del button. This will disable the function.

Comment: Insert changes the shape of the cursor, not the character printed when space bar is pressed.